# where to put code that effects multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Every day at, say 5pm I want to generate an Invoice model for all new Order models which have been generated in the past 24 hours.

What are some options for where this method should reside?

Are there any problems with having this as a method inside the Order model itself? e.g.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def generate_invoice
    invoice = Invoice.new
    ...
    return invoice
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a module and include that in your models

Ex:

```
module Invoice
  def generate_invoice
    invoice = Invoice.new
    ...
    return invoice
  end
end
```

and in your models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Invoice
end
```

HTH

Comment: Thx. What I ended up doing was moving as much as possible of the code into the models, and having the routine-specific code in a rake task which I can schedule. Seems the cleanest way for now.